# Array values transfer between 2 functions

Tags: javascript

I try to read an array using a function and use it in another function, however the second function does not seem to read it. What I am doing wrong?

```
  function calcDet () {   
            var A = [];     //generates the array
                for (var i = 0; i < k; i++) {
                    A[i] = [];
                    for (var j = 0; j < k; j++) {   
                        var id = "A" + (i + 1) + (j + 1);                   
                        A[i][j] =  parseFloat(document.getElementById(id).value);               
                    }
                }   
                alert (A);
            return (A); 
        }
        function calcRec() {            
                var s;
                var det;
                alert (A)
        }
```

Comment: thx for all the answers. I can't declare the variable globaly as it's length and values depend on user input. So I have first to read k and then read the array values. I will just use the second approach suggested (A = calcDet()). It works now so thanks a bunch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Frist way is

```
function function1()
{
  var valriable1=12;
  function2(val);
}

function function2(val)
{
  var variableoffunction1 = val;
}
```

Second way is

```
var globalvarialbe;
function function1()
{
  globalvarialbe=12;
  function2();
}

function function2()
{
  var local = globalvarialbe;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

firstly your array is not declared outside the function. its scope is limited to function body. but as your function returns the array back then try using it for initializing your local variable in other array. also this will work.
or 
try declaring it outside the functions

Comment: I expect better than that from a Byakugan.

Comment: nw does it complete u r expectations frm a byakugan:)

Comment: Now it does. An example would be great

Answer (score 1):

It's because JavaScript has a "functional scope". It means that whatever is declared inside the function cannot be seen by the outside, but what's outside can be seen from the inside.

In your case, you must declare the array outside the function.

```
var A = []

function calcDet(){...}

function calcRec(){
    alert(A);
}
```

or call the function and return `A`

```
function calcDet(){
    var A = [];
    ...
    return A;
}

function calcRec(){
    var A = calcDet(); //get A from calcDet
    alert(A);
}
```

Comment: @Truth updated it. and the OP didn't mention about the code living in the global scope. It could be living in another function or in a closure.

Answer (score 1):

You can't because you are declaring `A` locally in `calcDet`

One way is to declare `A` outside the function, or simply feed it into `calcRec`:

```
var A
function calcDet() {
   // code
}

function calcRec() {
   // code
}
```

or (better)

```
function calcRec() {            
   var s;
   var det;
   alert (calcDet())
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**[See this link about scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope)**.

The A variable, being declared inside of the function, is only scoped to that function. It will die after the function dies. You need to pass it as a parameter:

```
function calcRec(data) {            
        var s;
        var det;
        alert (data)
}
A = calcDet();
calcRec(A);
```